# DDMS not capturing camera preview on FroYo

Tags: android, ddms

I was working on an app that included camera preview, and with my old phone running 1.6 I could take screenshots with DDMS.  After getting a new phone with FroYo and updating to the latest SDK on the same dev machine, the camera preview layer is black when I do a screen capture.  I have an overlay layer on top, and that shows just fine.  The app runs fine on my phone and shows the preview as expected, it's just not showing up in screen caps.

Is there something I can look for in the debug output?  Is this a known issue that others are experiencing?

Comment: Just to say that I'm experiencing the same problem...